# how to download MS Excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have Node.js service that returns:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

And here is my Angular code to download it. And it works fine:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';

getXLS(){
    const type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

    const options = new RequestOptions({
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
        headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': type })
    });

    this.httpService.post(<url>, options)
        .catch(errorResponse => Observable.throw(errorResponse.json()))
        .map((response) => {
            if (response instanceof Response) {
                return response.blob();
            }
            return response;
        }).subscribe(data => saveAs(data, “temp.xlsx”),
        error => console.log(error));
   }
}
```

But I don't want to save it immediately. I want my getXLS() return that response. And then save it by other function

```
<button class="button" (click)="getXLS()">Save</button>
<button class="button" (click)="doSave()">Save</button>
```

How it can be done?

Comment: is there anything else you need help with? you seem to have not accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the file to be downloaded immediately, then do not use `saveAs` in subscribe. Instead just save the response in local variable.

```
getXLS(){
    const type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

    const options = new RequestOptions({
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
        headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': type })
    });

    this.httpService.post(<url>, options)
        .catch(errorResponse => Observable.throw(errorResponse.json()))
        .map((response) => {
            if (response instanceof Response) {
                return response.blob();
            }
            return response;
        }).subscribe(data => this.xmlBlob = data,  //assuming xmlBlob variable will be defined somewhere
        error => console.log(error));
   }
}
```

Then in your doSave method:

```
doSave() {
  saveAs(this.xmlBlob, “temp.xlsx”);
}
```

Comment: OK. .In response I get something like: PK

�L��ssL�[Content_Types].xml��Mn�0��=E�-J]TUE`џe�Tz7�Ƕ<��wb(�*J�`+�y�{v4O7����xW�Q1��k�������"CRN+��b(����|3;,EC�Ī�Va�8��>���5.dP�R-@��w����QN������V+K����wA"X�㮱c�B�`M���r��J�'�L=ؘ�n�(�������f�ѐ�T�W�r��X������eq��HJ_צ��U˒C����i-Zeܠ���Q�et� ����v��#$� ��^�ړi�Q�;E����}*�g�� �p~����y`#�dN��@d��O
��i�G�2�O&�PK .    How do I convert it in and save?

Comment: This is just blob. So yes it will look like this. The `saveAs` function provided by your file-saver plugin should take care of it. You just pass this blob.

Comment: OK.. right..saveAs should just save it... Seems something wrong with that blob. Because then the file cannot be opened in MS Excel. It says file is corrupted.

Comment: That is some other issue. Not related to how to get and then save later. Please accept the answer if it helped it.